# Whats the best way to ensure a line in a file exists?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

For example I have

```
<Home/>
wall
none
</Home>
```

what I need to do here is figure out a way to add "wall" within

```
<Home />

</Home>
```

and then ensure it is there in the file and if it is not I need to add it.

What is the best way to ensure "wall" exists?

What I tried is using a regex that goes:

```
^(<Home />.*\n)([^.]+</Home>.*)$
```

and a replace that goes

```
$1 wall\n$2
```

How will I add "wall" into that section in the file and ensure it is there meaning if its already in that section nothing changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(<Home\s*/>)((?:\R(?!(?:wall|</Home>)$).*)*\R</Home>)
```

and replace with `$1\nwall$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/27tiud/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(<Home\s*/>)` - Group 1: `<Home`, 0+ whitespaces, `/>`
- `((?:\R(?!(?:wall|</Home>)$).*)*\R</Home>)` - Group 2:

  - `(?:\R(?!(?:wall|</Home>)$).*)*` - 0+ consecutive occurrences of

    - `\R(?!(?:wall|</Home>)$)` - a linebreak sequence (`\R`) that is not followed with `wall` or `</Home>` as whole line text (with the help of the negative lookahead `(?!(?:wall|</Home>)$)`)
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars to the end of the line (as many as possible)
  - `\R` - a line break
  - `</Home>` - a `</Home>` substring.

The `$1` and `$2` are replacement backreferences that refer to the values captured within Groups 1 and 2.